# findViewById() returns null value in the sliding navigation drawer

Tags: android

I have textview in the sliding xml of  navigation drawer and when i am trying to access the textview its giving me null pointer error at the findviewId can anyone tell me how to access it ? i am trying to use it but i am not able to do it this way.....

```
    here is my code:



    public class AbstractActivity extends AppCompatActivity  implements View.OnClickListener{
        private String[] mPlanetTitles;
        private LinearLayout mDrawerList;
        protected DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
        protected ActionBarDrawerToggle mDrawerToggle;
        private CharSequence mDrawerTitle;
        private CharSequence mTitle;
        protected Toolbar toolbar;
        protected FrameLayout mFrameLayout;
         LinearLayout list0,list1,list2,list3,list4,list5,list6,list7,list8,list9,list10,list11,list12,list13,list14;
         FancyButton btnAdd,btnChange;
        private TextView txtUserName,txtUserDob,txtUserPlace;


        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_abstract);


            mFrameLayout = (FrameLayout)findViewById(R.id.main_activity_content_frame);

            txtUserName.findViewById(R.id.txtUserName);
            txtUserDob.findViewById(R.id.txtUserDob);
            txtUserPlace.findViewById(R.id.txtUserLocation);

            SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences(Const.Shared.MY_PREFERNCES,MODE_PRIVATE);
            String name = sharedPreferences.getString(Const.Shared.USER_NAME,null);
            int day = sharedPreferences.getInt(Const.Shared.DAY,0);
            int month = sharedPreferences.getInt(Const.Shared.MONTH,0);
            int year = sharedPreferences.getInt(Const.Shared.YEAR,0);
            String location = sharedPreferences.getString(Const.Shared.LOCATION,null);
            txtUserName.setText(name);
            txtUserDob.setText(day+"-"+month+"-"+year);
            txtUserPlace.setText(location);

            toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
            setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

            mPlanetTitles = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.planets_array);
            mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.main_activity_DrawerLayout);
            //mDrawerList = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.left_drawer);

            mTitle = mDrawerTitle = getTitle().toString();
            mDrawerLayout.closeDrawers();
            mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, mDrawerLayout,
                    toolbar, R.string.drawer_open, R.string.drawer_close){

                public void onDrawerClosed(View view) {
                    super.onDrawerClosed(view);
                    getSupportActionBar().setTitle(mTitle);
                    invalidateOptionsMenu(); // creates call to onPrepareOptionsMenu()
                }

                /** Called when a drawer has settled in a completely open state. */
                public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
                    super.onDrawerOpened(drawerView);
                    getSupportActionBar().setTitle(mDrawerTitle);
                    invalidateOptionsMenu(); // creates call to onPrepareOptionsMenu()
                }

                @Override
                public void onDrawerSlide(View drawerView, float slideOffset) {
                    // Disables the burger/arrow animation by default
                    super.onDrawerSlide(drawerView, 0);
                }


            };

            if (getSupportActionBar() != null) {
                getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
                getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
                getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
            }
            mDrawerToggle.syncState();
            mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);




            //View frameNavigation = findViewById(R.id.fram)
            list0 =(LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.listm0);
            list1 =(LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.listm1);
            list2 =(LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.listm2);
            list3 =(LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.listm3);
            list4 =(LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.listm4);
            list5 =(LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.listm5);
            list6 =(LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.listm6);
            list7 =(LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.listm7);
            list8 =(LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.listm8);
            list9 =(LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.listm9);
            list10 =(LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.listm10);
            list11 =(LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.listm11);
            list12 =(LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.listm12);
            list13 =(LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.listm13);
            list14 =(LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.listm14);
            btnAdd =(FancyButton)findViewById(R.id.btn_add);
            btnChange =(FancyButton)findViewById(R.id.btn_change);





        }

        public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
            // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
            getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);
            return true;


        }

        public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item){
            int items = item.getItemId();
            switch(items){



                case R.id.action_Contact_us:{
                    Intent intent = new Intent(this,Contact.class);
                    startActivity(intent);

                }break;

                case R.id.action_Aboutus:{
                    Intent intent = new Intent(this,AboutUs.class);
                    startActivity(intent);

                }break;

                case R.id.action_Profile:{
                    Intent intent = new Intent(this,HoroscopeChart.class);
                    startActivity(intent);

                }break;

            }

            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }


        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {


        }

        public void myclick(View v){
            int id = v.getId();

            switch (id) {
                case R.id.btn_add: {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(this, Form.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                }break;

                case R.id.btn_change: {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(this, Form.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                }break;
                case R.id.listm0: {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(this, DailyPrediction.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                }
                break;

                case R.id.listm1: {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(this, AstroDetailsMain.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                }
                break;

                case R.id.listm2: {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(this, HoroscopeChart.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                }
                break;

                case R.id.listm3: {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(this, PlanetaryPositions.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                }
                break;

                case R.id.listm4: {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(this, VimshottariDashaMain.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                }
                break;

                case R.id.listm5: {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(this, YoginiDashaMain.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                }
                break;

                case R.id.listm6: {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(this, ChardashaMain.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                }
                break;

                case R.id.listm7: {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(this, AshtakVarga.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                }
                break;

                case R.id.listm8: {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(this, Kalsarp.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                }
                break;

                case R.id.listm9: {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(this, Manglik.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                }
                break;

                case R.id.listm10: {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(this, PitraDosha.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                }
                break;
                case R.id.listm11: {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(this, Sadhesati.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                }
                break;

                case R.id.listm12: {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(this, AscendantReport.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                }
                break;

                case R.id.listm13: {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(this, HouseReports.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                }
                break;
                case R.id.listm14: {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(this, SignReport.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                }
                break;

            }

        }
    }

         <android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout  
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/main_activity_DrawerLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <!-- The main content view -->
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <include layout="@layout/kundli_toolbar" />

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/main_activity_content_frame"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <!-- The navigation drawer -->

        <FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
            xmlns:fancy="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="start"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            >

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical">


                <ScrollView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:background="@android:color/white"
                    android:clipToPadding="false"
                    android:paddingBottom="10dp"
                    android:paddingTop="0dp">

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:background="@android:color/white"
                        android:orientation="vertical"
                        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                        xmlns:fancy="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
                        <LinearLayout
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:orientation="vertical"

                            android:background="@drawable/png"
                            >

                            <LinearLayout
                                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                                android:orientation="vertical"
                                android:gravity="center"

                                >

                                <LinearLayout
                                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                    android:orientation="horizontal"

                                    >
                                    <LinearLayout
                                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                                        android:orientation="vertical"
                                        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                                        android:layout_marginTop="10dp">
                                        <TextView
                                            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                                            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                            android:id="@+id/txtUserName"
                                            android:textColor="@android:color/white"

                                            android:textSize="22dp"/>
                                        <TextView
                                            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                                            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                                            android:id="@+id/txtUserDob"
                                            android:textSize="16dp"/>
                                        <TextView
                                            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                                            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                                            android:id="@+id/txtUserLocation"
                                            android:textSize="16dp"/>
                                    </LinearLayout>
                                </LinearLayout>



                            </LinearLayout>
                            <LinearLayout
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:orientation="horizontal"
                                android:layout_marginTop="10dp">
                                <mehdi.sakout.fancybuttons.FancyButton
                                    android:id="@+id/btn_add"
                                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                    android:paddingBottom="5dp"
                                    android:paddingLeft="20dp"
                                    android:paddingRight="20dp"
                                    android:paddingTop="5dp"
                                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                                    android:onClick="myclick"
                                    fancy:fb_borderColor="#FFFFFF"
                                    fancy:fb_borderWidth="1dp"
                                    fancy:fb_defaultColor="#7ab800"
                                    fancy:fb_focusColor="#9bd823"

                                    fancy:fb_radius="30dp"
                                    fancy:fb_text="Add Profile"
                                    fancy:fb_textColor="#FFFFFF" />
                                <mehdi.sakout.fancybuttons.FancyButton
                                    android:id="@+id/btn_change"
                                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                    android:paddingBottom="5dp"
                                    android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                                    android:paddingRight="10dp"
                                    android:paddingTop="5dp"
                                    android:onClick="myclick"
                                    android:layout_marginLeft="40dp"
                                    fancy:fb_borderColor="#FFFFFF"
                                    fancy:fb_borderWidth="1dp"
                                    fancy:fb_defaultColor="#7ab800"
                                    fancy:fb_focusColor="#9bd823"
                                    fancy:fb_radius="30dp"
                                    fancy:fb_text="Change Profile"
                                    fancy:fb_textColor="#FFFFFF" />
                            </LinearLayout>
                        </LinearLayout>
                        <LinearLayout
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:orientation="vertical"

                            >
                            <LinearLayout
                                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:id="@+id/listm0"
                                android:orientation="vertical"
                                android:onClick="myclick"
                                >

                                <LinearLayout
                                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                    android:layout_height="40dp"
                                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                                    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                                    android:weightSum="1">

                                    <TextView
                                        android:layout_weight="1"
                                        android:id="@+id/txtPlace"
                                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                                        android:text="@string/todays_prediction"
                                        android:textSize="16dp"
                                        android:paddingLeft="30dp"
                                        android:gravity="center_vertical"/>
                                </LinearLayout>

                            </LinearLayout>
                            <View android:layout_height="1dp"
                                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                android:background="@color/gray_light"></View>
                            <LinearLayout
                                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:id="@+id/listm1"
                                android:orientation="vertical"
                                android:onClick="myclick"
                                >

                                <LinearLayout
                                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                    android:layout_height="40dp"
                                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                                    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                                    android:weightSum="1">

                                    <TextView
                                        android:layout_weight="1"
                                        android:id="@+id/txtPlace"
                                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                                        android:text="@string/astro_details"
                                        android:textSize="16dp"
                                        android:paddingLeft="30dp"
                                        android:gravity="center_vertical"/>
                                </LinearLayout>

                            </LinearLayout>

                            <LinearLayout
                                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:id="@+id/listm5"
                                android:orientation="vertical"
                                android:onClick="myclick"
                                >

                                <LinearLayout
                                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                    android:layout_height="40dp"
                                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                                    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                                    android:weightSum="1">

                                    <TextView
                                        android:layout_weight="1"
                                        android:id="@+id/txtPlace"
                                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                                        android:text="@string/yogini"
                                        android:textSize="16dp"
                                        android:paddingLeft="30dp"
                                        android:gravity="center_vertical"/>
                                </LinearLayout>

                            </LinearLayout>

                            <View android:layout_height="1dp"
                                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                android:background="@color/gray_light"></View>
                        </LinearLayout>




                    </LinearLayout>


                </ScrollView>

            </LinearLayout>


        </FrameLayout>


    </android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Comment: post logcat trash here.

Comment: just post relevant codes not all of your project

Comment: `txtUserName.findViewById(R.id.txtUserName);` - This is not how you use `findViewById()` to initialize a `View` reference. It should be `txtUserName = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtUserName);`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace this

```
 txtUserName.findViewById(R.id.txtUserName);
 txtUserDob.findViewById(R.id.txtUserDob);
 txtUserPlace.findViewById(R.id.txtUserLocation);
```

with this

```
 txtUserName =  (TextView)findViewById(R.id.txtUserName);
 txtUserDob = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.txtUserDob);
 txtUserPlace = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.txtUserLocation);
```